# Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument - Lambda function

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, remove-if

I am getting the following error when building my code:

```
Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument
```

I read the other posts concerning this error and added the keyword `this` inside my *lambda* function but I am still getting the same error.

I am trying to use a class member function inside another class member function using a C++ lambda function (`std::remove_if`).

```
class LineSegments
{
public:
   LineSegments();

   float getClockwiseAngle0to180(const float& dx1, const float& dx2, const float& dy1, const float& dy2);
   void eliminateParallelLineSegments(std::vector<cv::Vec4f>& lines);
   ~LineSegments();
};

// Constructors
LineSegments::LineSegments() {}

// Destructors
LineSegments::~LineSegments() {}

float LineSegments::getClockwiseAngle0to180(const float& dx1, const float& dx2, const float& dy1, const float& dy2) {
   float dot = dx1 * dx2 + dy1 * dy2;
   float det = dx1 * dy2 - dy1 * dx2;
   float angle = -atan2(det, dot);
   angle = angle * (180 / CV_PI);
   if (angle < 0) {
      angle = angle + 360;
   }
   if (angle >= 180) {
      angle = angle - 180;
   }
   return angle;
}

void LineSegments::eliminateParallelLineSegments(std::vector<cv::Vec4f>& lines)
{
   lines.erase(remove_if(lines.begin() + 1, lines.end(), [this](const Vec4f& left_line, const Vec4f& right_line)
      {
         return (abs((getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, left_line[2] - left_line[0], 1, left_line[3] - left_line[1]) - getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, right_line[2] - right_line[0], 1, right_line[3] - right_line[1]))) < 2);
      })
      , lines.end()
   );
}
```

I guess it is a simple mistake but I couldn't find it for more than one hour now ;). This is just a minimal example.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, there doesn't seem to be any point to those functions being members of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the predicate of your `std::remove_if()` which should be unary predicates. (unary predicate are just functions that take a single parameter and return a Boolean value).

See this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

> **Parameters of `std::remove_if()`**
>
> 1. **first, last** : Forward iterators to the initial and final positions in a sequence of move-assignable elements. The range used is
>      [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last,
>      including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by
>      last.
> 2. **pred** : Unary function that accepts an element in the range as argument, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned
>      indicates whether the element is to be removed (if true, it is
>      removed). The function shall not modify its argument. This can either
>      be a function pointer or a function object.

```
[this] (const Vec4f &left_line, const Vec4f &right_line) 
{
     return (abs((getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, left_line[2] - left_line[0], 1, left_line[3] - left_line[1]) - getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, right_line[2] - right_line[0], 1, right_line[3] - right_line[1]))) < 2);
 })
```

Here, in your **lambda function**  you are trying to pass two arguments (i.e, `const Vec4f &left_line` and `const Vec4f &right_line`) which is not possible. It should be an unary predicate.

---

> "I read the other posts concerning this error and added the keyword
>   `this` inside my lambda function but I am still getting the same error."

It has nothing to do with current object. Therefore, no need of using `this` here. You could also define an independent function as you use vector of objects of this class. Or in other-words, you can define `getClockwiseAngle0to180()` as a non-member function.

---

A possible solution could be, something like as follows.

```
auto left_line = Vec4f[1]; // as per your first element of your vector(Vec4f) that you want as lhs

lines.erase(std::remove_if(lines.begin() + 1, lines.end(),
[&] (Vec4f& right_line)->bool
{
    auto temp = abs((getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, left_line[2] - left_line[0], 1, left_line[3] - left_line[1]) -
                     getClockwiseAngle0to180(0, right_line[2] - right_line[0], 1, right_line[3] - right_line[1]));

    left_line = right_line; // now your left_line  = right_line

    return temp < 2 ;
}), lines.end());
```

**PS**: it hasn't tested.

Comment: You mean that the function that `std::remove_if` takes as it's third argument takes only one argument.